# navigating to local anchor tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my Intel XDK app auto navigate to a new DIV with id="page_6" when a function fails as follow:

```
var fail = function(){ 
    alert("geolocation failed");
    window.location = window.location + "#page_6";
};
```

However, the app does NOT navigate to the new DIV.

Any ideas?

Comment: `window.location.hash = 'page_6'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `window.location.href`

```
window.location.href = window.location + "#page_6"
```

Saying that, simply using `window.location` (as in your example code) works for me.
Are you sure that your fail callback is being executed?

Comment: Hi
Yes, I've tried many combinations already, including document.location.

I know the function is called since the "alert" is definitely triggered.

Comment: Which browser is this happening in?

Comment: Also, from where are you calling this? Is there an iframe involved?

Comment: Hi
This is not from a traditional browser - it's what I assume is a webkit browser as part of the Intel XDK platform for the mobile device. There are no iframes involved.

The "application" is in essence a straight forward HTML5 page, where there are a couple of divs, and this one function, as per my original post, tries to "redirect" to that div with id=page_6 when the function is called. Elsewhere in the page, I use a href="" tags to get the same thing done onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution.
Set a marker div with id to navigate to:
div id="a3" /div
When a condition is met [mine is in a scripted 'loop with' an int++ creating the background changes and using 'if' to evaluate when I want to navigate to div id a3]
add the following script line window.location.assign("#a3");